# SWIFT: I don't get notifications from my CloudKit app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, notifications, cloudkit

Here is my code:

```
    @IBAction func sendSweet(sender: AnyObject) {

    //delegate method

    let newSweet = CKRecord(recordType: "Extra1")
    newSweet["content"] = textField.text

    let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    publicData.saveRecord(newSweet, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.sweets.insert(newSweet, atIndex: 0)
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Top)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
                self.textField.text = ""
                self.textField.resignFirstResponder()



            })


        }})
    // Put the CloudKit private database in a constants
    let privateDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

    // Create subscription and set three of its properties (an id, a predicate, and options)
    let friendsSubscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Extra1",
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE"),
        subscriptionID: "Extra1",
        options: .FiresOnRecordCreation)

    // Create a notification and set two of its properties (alertBody and shouldBadge)
    let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.alertBody = "New message in Lms Chat"
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = false

    // Attach the notification to the subscription
    friendsSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    // Save the subscription in the private database
    privateDatabase.saveSubscription(friendsSubscription) {recordReturned, error in
        // On the main thread, display an error/success message in the textView
        if error != nil {
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                self.textField.text = "Cloud error\n\(error!.localizedDescription)"
            }
        } else {
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                self.textField.text = ""
            }
        }
    }

}
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  //delegate method
    return false
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true

}
```

It's a messaging app so people can message eachother but I also want them to recieve notifications. This is the code for notifications and I also have some code for notifications in App Delegate:

```
import UIKit
    import CloudKit

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let cloudKitNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo as! [String:NSObject])

    if cloudKitNotification.notificationType == CKNotificationType.Query {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("performReload", object: nil)
        })

    }

}

func resetBadge () {
    let badgeReset = CKModifyBadgeOperation(badgeValue: 0)
    badgeReset.modifyBadgeCompletionBlock = { (error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        }

    }

    CKContainer.defaultContainer().addOperation(badgeReset)
}


func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    resetBadge()

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("performReload", object: nil)
    })
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    resetBadge()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

}
```

But notifications do not come in even though I have all of the code needed to make notifications every time someone sends a message. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Someone answered me before saying:

You are adding data to the public database but you are creating your subscription on the private database. One of those two needs to be changed to match the other.

So I changed the `let privateDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase` to `let privateDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase`

Comment: Too much code! Please remove irrelevant info so it is easier for us to debug

Comment: @penatheboss Its showing my code maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: No your code is fine. It's just that there is too much. Only show whatever is relevant to your problem

Answer (score 0):

In your app Delegate, you are missing this method :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    print(deviceToken)       // This is the device token
    var token: String = "\(deviceToken)"    /// formatted token.

    let rawtoken = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "")
    let cleantoken = rawtoken.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "")
    var finaltoken = cleantoken.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    // Send device token to server

            }
        }
    }
```

WHat I mean is that to send notification, you register user for push Notification. For the case If the register succeeds, you have to implement the method above.
if the registeration fails, you have to implement this :

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print(error)

}
```

Comment: Here can you please help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495254/swift-i-dont-get-notifications-from-my-cloudkit-app

Comment: Hey, I'll help in a bit. I'm a bit busy for now.

Comment: I added what you told me to add but notifications still dont show.

Comment: have any other ideas?